# Oxidation on DIP Package Pins

Tags: integrated-circuit

The pins of my CI GAL are oxidized. I would like to know whether this is likely to cause a serious problem with functionality of the device.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That depends on whether you plan to use it.

Comment: This may be better-received with a title that reflects the actual question. Humor is welcome on forums, but this is not a forum.

Comment: If used for hobby-stuff...whatever. If used for aerospace: big no no! Used as industrial replacement: Little bit of "scotch-brite-love" and re-tinning ... should be good enough imho.

Comment: It is sort of relevant _how_ you are going to use it.  Flat socket?  Precision socket?  Directly soldered in?

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on what the coating material is.  If the pins are simply coated with a tin or tin/lead solder, simply cleaning them is sufficient.  As mentioned in the comments, Scotch-Brite pad works well.  Personally, I use a fiberglass brush - carefully.  You just want to remove the surface oxidation.

The socket the chip goes into is also important.  Either Amp Diplomate (tm) socket or machined-pin (Mill Max) socket is best.  Be warned there are MANY inferior DIP sockets in use yesterday!

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and sorry for the humorous title (JYelton)